# Remotely access mysql db on vm from windows as host

Tags: mysql, vmware, remote-access, database

I have ubuntu on vmware. I've installed mysql-server on it. And now I'd like to connect to this db directly from the Host(windows) machine. Ubuntu is connected to the router via bridge. I can ping it and have remote access to system. But I want to connect to the database only. How do I do this?

Comment: Please tell us about your setup. Does the VM have internet access? How have you set up its network card? What is its IP? How exactly do you want to access the DB? Using what tools? Imagine you know nothing about what you're doing, would you understand this question?

Comment: Yes, it has. I set it up as a brige. VM machine has his ip adress. I'd like to get acceess to db via commmand promt

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and include this information. Preferably also add a screenshot of the VM's network settings. Tell us if the IP is in the same subnet as the host, tell us if you can ping the guest from the host, what commands you tried and how they fell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL server not accessible from remote machine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159053/mysql-server-not-accessible-from-remote-machine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should allow remote access to mysql from command line inside your virtual machine (assuming you don't have any gui tools to connect to mysql like phpmyadmin and mysql-workbench)

1. as root, open your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with your favorite editor
2. look for the `[mysqld]` section, and in there for the `bind-address` keyword. This usually is set to `127.0.0.1` -- change that to match your "normal" IP-address
3. save the file, and reload the service (e.g. using `service mysql restart`)

Remember you must enable your remote users to access their database(s) from remote, by setting the appropriate GRANTs -- e.g.

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO remoteuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SomePASSWORD';
```

Note the `@'%'`, which means "from any host".

Comment: @nikgul please mark it as answer

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954395/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-server-running-on-a-virtual-machine), which says to set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`